# Best approach to change the Program Files directory

Tags: windows-8.1

I am about to reinstall windows 8.1 on my laptop and have 1 SSD and 1 HDD.
My idea is to install Windows on the SSD and configure it to set the default program files directory to the HDD.

However I'd like to know what the best way to approach this is, I think I tried this earlier after the installation by changing a registery key and I thought I had a few issues with previously installed programs not beeing recognized anymore (can't remember what the errors were about).

Is there someone who could advice me on what the best approach would be to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/nifty-way-safely-move-folders-or-programs-another-drive-or-partition-windows-7.htm). It moves the `Program Files` folder to another drive then makes a symbolic link between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, albeit the most tedious, is to manually specify the directory where each program installs during the install.

Microsoft [doesn't support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700) changing the default directory with the registry due to issues with default Microsoft programs and updates.

Unfortunately, this is also the only way to change the "Default" location.